# Is there a RanorexViewer-Standalone?

Tags: ranorex

How can I make a Ranorex test report available to colleagues without them having to go through a complete Ranorex installation on their computers? Is there such a thing as a RanorexViewer standalone?

Answer (score 1):

When it's not an issue for you to change the Ranorex reporting options in your project:
Ranorex supports reporting to different formats which do not require a Ranorex installation (e.g. HTML or PDF).

The reporting options can be changed in the test suite's properties dialog in the 'Report' tab.
[image: ranorex studio screenshot]
(First Screenshot from Ranorex documentation)
[image: Propterties dialog]
After enabling HTML/PDF reports, they usually placed in the same directory the test suite is in. More information can be found on their [user guide](https://support.ranorex.com/userguide/ranorex-studio-fundamentals/reporting/introduction/)

In my experience the HTML reports are a bit fiddly when opened directly from the file system. The report tries to load resources from other files which most modern browsers do not allow due to the [CORS same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). This can easily be avoided by providing the reports on a web server or by using MS Internet Explorer (or Edge with IE compatibility mode) which treats local files as "same origin".

Answer (score -1):

Ranorex does not yet support a standalone RanorexViewer (this was confirmed to me by Ranorex support on 29 May 2023), therefore the following workaround:

If not yet installed, download the latest version of Ranorex Studio here: https://www.ranorex.com/download-archive/

Copy the following files into a separate folder (correct for Ranorex 10.7.0):

[image]

After starting the RanorexViewer.exe you can open a Ranorex Report (.rxlog).

Licence: Ranorex support writes in the forum: "no licence leased" (Source: https://www.ranorex.info/test-reports-to-non-ranorex-users-how-t14836.html#p56989)

Troubleshooting: When starting on a fresh Windows server (e.g. 2019), the Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration (Server Manager -> Local Server -> IE Enhanced Security Configuration) prevents the display of the complete test report.